# Delays in for loop

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

So i am writing a code for DES.But now i have hit a roadblock which i cant pass.

```html
module initialPermutation(cipher,plain);
  output reg [63:0]cipher;
  input [63:0]plain;
  integer i,j,k;
  
  initial
    begin
      for(i=57,k=0;i<=63;i=i+2)
        begin
          for(j=i;j>=i-56;j=j-8,k=k+1)
            begin
              cipher[k]=plain[j];
            end
        end
      for(i=56;i<=62;i=i+2)
        begin
          for(j=i;j>=i-56;j=j-8,k=k+1)
            begin
              cipher[k]=plain[j];
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

This is the initial permutation which runs perfectly fine...but for the final permutation..

```html
module finalPermutation(cipher,plain);
  output reg [63:0]cipher;
  input [63:0]plain;
  integer i,c;
  
  initial
    begin
      for(i=39,c=0;i>=32;i=i-1,c=c+1)
        cipher[0+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=7,c=0;i>=0;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[1+c*8]=plain[i];
 
      for(i=47,c=0;i>=40;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[2+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=15,c=0;i>=8;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[3+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=55,c=0;i>=48;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[4+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=24,c=0;i>=16;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[5+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=63,c=0;i>=56;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[6+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=31,c=0;i>=24;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[7+c*8]=plain[i];
     
    end
endmodule
```

this is the code.....it does not run and gives only "xxxx...."...but if i write it like this...

```html
module finalPermutation(cipher,plain);
  output reg [63:0]cipher;
  input [63:0]plain;
  integer i,c;
  
  initial
    begin
      #1;
      for(i=39,c=0;i>=32;i=i-1,c=c+1)
        cipher[0+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=7,c=0;i>=0;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[1+c*8]=plain[i];
 
      for(i=47,c=0;i>=40;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[2+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=15,c=0;i>=8;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[3+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=55,c=0;i>=48;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[4+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=24,c=0;i>=16;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[5+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=63,c=0;i>=56;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[6+c*8]=plain[i];
      
      for(i=31,c=0;i>=24;i=i-1,c=c+1)
          cipher[7+c*8]=plain[i];
     
    end
endmodule
```

where i have inserted a delay after initial statement it runs perfectly fine...both initalPermutation and finalPermutation looks quite same yet one does not run without delay...where is the difference??? And what should i do to remove the delay in finalPermutation?
here is the stimulus block for refernce...

```html
module stimulus;
  reg [63:0]plain;
  wire [63:0]out;
  reg [63:0]key;
  
  finalPermutation i(out,plain);
  initial
    begin
      plain=64'b110001111;
      #2 $display("%b ",out);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition. All `initial` blocks in all `module`s execute concurrently. So if your stimulus module's initial block executes after the other initial block, the other blocks do not see a change on their inputs.

But one does not model hardware with initial blocks. They need so be models sensitive to their inputs for combinational logic, or to the edge of a clock for sequential logic.

Comment: But the first module is running just fine.

Comment: As I said, its a race condition between initial blocks. (And now Greg)

Answer (score 0):

`initial` statements and blocks run only one at time 0. If there are multiple `initial`s in the simulation, then there is no guaranteed determinate order in evaluating them. The IEEE1364 (Verilog) & IEEE1800 (SystemVerilog) intentionally allows this type of indeterminism. Simulators tend the order the evaluation based on compiling and instantiation order. You need to write your code in a way that it will not be impacted by this scheduling order.

With `initial` blocks and statements, there should be no dependence on non-constants. The only exception is for non-synthesizer code (like testbenches and behavioral models for analog components) after blocking statements.

When depended on input signals, combinational RTL logic should use `always_comb` (SystemVerilog) or `always @*` (Verilog). If you get to choose between Verilog and SystemVerilog, go the SystemVerilog route. `always @*` does not guaranty to be evaluated at time-0 (optional for simulator). Sequential RTL logic should use `always_ff @(...)` (SystemVerilog) or `always @(...)` (Verilog), where `...` in a posedge or negedge clocking signal.

In `initialPermutation` and `finalPermutation` change `initial` to `always_comb` and you should get the non-X results. If you go with the Verilog `always @*` strategy, then you may want to add a `#1` before assigning `plain` in your testbench.